# I want to verify an EVM chain blockhash using the block header and its content

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, web3js, ethers.js, go-ethereum

I am trying to verify the blocks without having the access to an RPC, I using blockheader and trying to generate a blockhash using the data in blockheader, cannot figureout the exact flow for it.

Written multiple scripts like below but not able to get exact match till now.

```
const {
      hash,
      parentHash,
      sha3Uncles,
      miner,
      stateRoot,
      transactionsRoot,
      logsBloom,
      difficulty,
      number,
      gasLimit,
      gasUsed,
      timestamp,
      extraData,
      mixHash,
      nonce,
    } = await web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber);
 preEncode = [
      parentHash,
      sha3Uncles,
      miner,
      stateRoot,
      transactionsRoot,
      logsBloom,
      web3.utils.toHex(difficulty),
      web3.utils.toHex(number),
      web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
      web3.utils.toHex(gasUsed),
      web3.utils.toHex(timestamp),
      extraData,
      mixHash,
      nonce,
    ];
   // getting RLP hash
   let encoded = util.rlp.encode(preEncode);
   // Hashing the RLP output
    const hashedOutput = web3.utils.sha3(
      web3.utils.sha3(util.bufferToHex(encoded))
    );
```